# Question and all existing answers should be visible while answering

Tags: feature-request, answers, user-interface

When there are 3 or more answers for a question adding a another answer becomes very difficult as the user has to scroll each time he wants to see the question.

This hampers the speed of writing the answer and also frustrates the user if the question has, say 13 answers.

The scrolling time is significant for popular questions with more amount of answers. This will discourage any late-comers from answering any popular questions.

Hope this issue is resolved soon

**My suggestion**

- I think they should create a static answer box which will not scroll along with the rest of the page. In this way all the answers and the question could be referred to while answering a question.
- Or my other suggestion which is a secondary one is that the question should be static. But I don't prefer this one because all the other answers cannot be referred to in this case.(In the above case the question and all answers can be referred )

Comment: When you edit an existing answer on a separate page, there is a slider at the top of the page to show/hide the question. Is that what you're aiming at (I know it's not available for new answers, but it could be rather easy to port it over).

Comment: @Glorfindel Yes i got it. But You can't see all other answers while editing a existing answer. And another problem is that it is not available for new answers

Comment: @Glorfindel But I dont think it would be easy to port it over to all stack exchange websites

Comment: It already works like this on all sites, but it's not easy to port over to new answers. OTOH, it's easier than developing such functionality from scratch.

Comment: @Glorfindel Do you think my question is a valid point because i am surprised nobody said anything about this earlier

Comment: I guess it could be useful, though I can't imagine I'll need it. One can always open the question in another tab while writing the answer.

Comment: @Glorfindel But it would be cumbersome if one wants to consult existing answers

Comment: related: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168)

Comment: @gnat no my question is different because in the current UI we can't even check the question (but we can check the question while editing a existing answer)